# неожиданный результат стандартного алгоритма кучи

Tags: c++, алгоритм

В каком то отрезке кода решил создать кучу и получил не тот результат. (Ну понятно, что можно пользоваться и priority_queue)

```
//библиотеки подключены
template < class C >
void show(const C& cont, size_t n = 25, const char* del = " ")
{
    size_t i = 1;
    for (auto val : cont) {
        std::cout << val << del;
        if (!(i % n))  std::cout <<'\n';
        ++i;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //...
    vector<string> vh{"angl", "rus", "usa", "esp"};
    std::set<string> s(vh.begin(), vh.end());

    std::make_heap(vh.begin(), vh.end());
    show(s, 4);  //angl esp rus usa  //(ok)
    show(vh, 4);  // все нормально, но результат непонятен
                  //выдает:  usa rus angl(?) esp    

    return 0;
}
```

помогите пожалуйста понять, почему после алгоритма make_heap, третий элемент вектора не "esp", а "angl"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое первое, это надо вспомнить, как именно хранится [структура хипа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0) в массиве (векторе).

В примере с вопроса это будет так

```
      usa
     /  \
   rus  angl
   / \  /  \
esp  _ _   _
```

(подчеркивания - это просто пустышки, для красоты).

Не сложно убедиться, что все свойства хипа выполняются. Почему же `angl` и `esp` не поменяны местами? Можно и так. В этом случае все равно хип будет корректный. Но просто так сработал алгоритм Heapify.

Думаю, что Вы решили, что порядок должен быть `usa rus esp angl`, потому что думаете, что данные в хипе отсортированы в памяти. Но это не так. Просто в этом примере так все сложилось.

Comment: често говоря не знал, что хип это дерево, теперь для меня прояснилось многое - спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Куча, реализуемая стандартной библиотекой С++ - это абстрактная структура данных, которая гарантирует только следующие свойства:

- После выполнения `std::make_heap` в начале диапазона будет располагаться его максимальный элемент
- Максимальный элемент можно извлечь из кучи через `std::pop_heap`, а новый элемент можно включить в кучу через `std::push_heap` за логарифмическое время

То есть за исключением самого первого элемента, порядок элементов в диапазоне кучи совершенно *непредсказуем*. Рассматривать этот порядок и делать на его основе какие-то выводы бессмысленно.

Кучи бывают разные (бинарные, биномиальные, Фибоначчи). Реализации стандартной библиотеки С++ обычно реализуют классическую бинарную кучу. Но и в ней порядок элементов в диапазоне, преобразованном в кучу при помощи `std::make_heap`, неоднозначен, кроме самого первого элемента.

Comment: **"После выполнения std::make_heap в начале диапазона будет располагаться его минимальный элемент"** нет. там же написано "max heap" (ну только если stl никто не поломал и компаратор не подсунул). **"порядок элементов в диапазоне кучи совершенно непредсказуем."** предсказуем. К примеру, самый минимальный элемент вряд ли будет вторым или третим в списке (если конечно весь список больше 8-10 элементов и они разные).

Comment: @KoVadim: Это я запутался, переводя на простой язык оригинальное утверждение из стандарта "в диапазоне нет элемента, большего чем первый". Да, конечно, самый первый элемент - максимальный, а не минимальный. Что касается предсказуемости порядка, я лишь излагал то, что содержится в стандарте языка. Если там ничего не сказано о порядке, то он формально непредсказуем.

Comment: @KoVadim,   чувствуется дух большого мастера: "мое понимание правильного ответа часто идет в разрез с мнением "вахтеров"  ". Прямо в десятку!..